# Ajax redireciona para url

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Bom dia galera,

estou com um pequeno probleminha, imagino ser simples, mas, não estou conseguindo resolver.

Seguinte, tenho de fazer o upload de uma foto de perfil do usuário, o código esta funcionando beleza:

> JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".change-photograph").change(function (event) {
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (ext == "gif" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "png") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            $(reader).load(function (event) {
                $(".img-photograph").attr("src", event.target.result);
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

            $("#save-photograph").click();
        } else {
            dialog("Alerta", "O arquivo selecionado é inválido.")
        }
    });
$("#uploadPhotograph").submit(function () {
        var formData = new FormData($("#uploadPhotograph")[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/User/UploadPhotograph",
            ajaxasync: true,
            data: formData,
            success: function () {
                addMensagem("Foto alterada com sucesso.");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.x);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
function addMensagem(mensage) {
$("#mensagens").append("<li style='overflow: hidden; margin: 4px 0px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgb(124, 221, 119); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 4px; color: darkgreen; width: 310px; cursor: pointer; height: 52px; background-color: rgb(188, 245, 188);' class='close-mensagem animated flipInX'><div class='noty_bar noty_type_success'><div class='noty_message' style='font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; text-align: center; padding: 10px; width: auto; position: relative;'><span class='noty_text'>" + mensage + "</span></div></div></li>");
```

}

> C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadPhotograph(UserViewModel user, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            var edit = false;
            if (user.user_photograph != null)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/" + user.user_photograph)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/" + user.user_photograph));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                edit = true;
            }

            String[] strName = file.FileName.Split('.');
            String strExt = strName[strName.Count() - 1];
            string pathSave = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", Server.MapPath("~/assets/usersPhoto/"), user.Id, strExt);
            String pathBase = String.Format("/assets/usersPhoto/{0}.{1}", user.Id, strExt);
            file.SaveAs(pathSave);

            if (edit)
                _userAppService.EditPhotograph(user.Id, pathBase);
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

O meu problema é que depois que ele realiza isso tudo bonitinho ele redireciona pra essa view, ele tinha que continuar no perfil do usuário, não redirecionar pra lugar algum.
Alguém sabe oque está acontecendo, não tenho a mínima ideia do que possa ser.

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Comment: Poderia postar a função addMensagem() para analisarmos?

Comment: Claro, vou editar.

Comment: Tenta adicionar o preventDefault(); no evento de submit.

Comment: Aí tiro o return false?

Comment: Se eu colocar o preventDefault() não executa nada da função.